# Load Report Failed Error show while direct printing crystal report vb.net(Not Every Time) Pin

Tags: c#, vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm using this code to print a crystal report without a preview. Sometimes a Load Report Failed error shows up. When I close and reopen the application, the report will printed. How can I resolve this error without needing to restart the application?

My code:

```
Dim crtableLogoninfo As New TableLogOnInfo
Dim crConnectionInfo As New ConnectionInfo
Dim CrTables As Tables
''  Dim CrTable As Table
Dim TableCounter
Dim crReportDocument As New ReportDocument
Dim crParameterDiscreteValue As ParameterDiscreteValue
Dim crParameterFieldDefinitions As ParameterFieldDefinitions
Dim crParameterFieldLocation As ParameterFieldDefinition
Dim crParameterValues As ParameterValues
Dim billno As New InfoGeneration
Dim sname As ConfigurationSettings
crReportDocument.Load(Application.StartupPath & "\Reports\rptsinv.rpt")
With crConnectionInfo
    .ServerName = sname.AppSettings("servername")
    .DatabaseName = sname.AppSettings("dbname")
    .UserID = sname.AppSettings("username")
    .Password = sname.AppSettings("password")
End With
CrTables = crReportDocument.Database.Tables
For Each CrTable In CrTables
    crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo
    crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo
    CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo)
Next

crParameterFieldDefinitions = crReportDocument.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
crParameterFieldLocation = crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("s_id")
crParameterValues = crParameterFieldLocation.CurrentValues
crParameterDiscreteValue = New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterDiscreteValue
crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = txts_id.Text
crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue)
crParameterFieldLocation.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues)
crReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(txtcopies.Text, False, 0, 0)
```

Comment: I am not sure why someone upvoted this question.  It is very difficult even to understand.  Please edit your question and be sure all the code is showing as code and reads like it does in visual studio, with indents etc.  Also be sure to include the exact error you are getting and that its clear which line of your code is breaking.